# How to merge two video using FFMPeg library on Android

Tags: java, arraylist, ffmpeg, mp4, android-ffmpeg

How to merge two video using FFMPEG Library on Android studio? I want to get first video from url.

Comment: SO is no _how-to or coding service_. Please read [ask] and show your efforts by posting an [example] where we can start guiding you on the last-mile.

Comment: "Merge" is too ambiguous. Do you want to mux both videos into one file as two separate streams? Or do you want to concatenate them so one plays after the other? Or do you want picture-in-picture? Or side-by-side? What about audio? By "FFMPeg library" do you mean libavcodec, libavformat, etc, or the `ffmpeg` command-line tool?